# Can't add value from other DB on many-to-may field in django

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

Here's my code

```
a =  Approver.objects.create(title = 'Tester')
a.save()
p = Profile.objects.create(name="Test")
p.save()
a.users.add(p)
```

I'm getting this error after

```
ValueError: Cannot add "<Profile: TEST>": instance is on database "default", value is on database "profiles_db"
```

Here's my model

```
class Approver(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True)
```

The Profile model come from another app which connects to a different database.

Is it not possible?

Comment: It's not possible to have relationships across different databases, no

Comment: If you can't store them in one database I would suggest to store `id` as `ListField` instead of `ManyToMany` field.

Comment: Thats really sad

Comment: @SergeyPugach If i do ListField, how can i use django-admin's autocomplete_fields?